# is linking performance affected on whether a symbol is marked as local or global in the .obj file?

Tags: c++, linker

I am trying to find ways to reduce linking time for my program.

I have noticed that there are a lot of functions in my codebase, which have not been specified as `static`, hence they are treated as `extern`.

If I specify them as `static`, they will get internal linkage.
I can verify this by running the name-mangling command on the object file (**nm** in linux):

Functions specified as `static` have a local symbol (e.g. 't') instead of a global symbol ('T').

**Q:** will the Linking time be notably reduced if enough symbols (functions) are converted from global (extern) to local (static)?

**Q:** Should I expect similar results if the objects have been created using a 'Release' compilation instead of 'Debug' compilation?

**Q:** Does the linkage specifier (`extern`/`static`) have any effect in the size of the object files?

*Note:* this question is about linking speed and object file size.
It is not about the implications of having functions implicitly declared as extern.

Comment: No. What results? No.

Comment: It is still a good idea to mark local helper functions as static, because fewer global names reduces the risk of accidental name collisions between different parts of the app.

Answer (score 1):

> will the Linking time be notably reduced if enough symbols (functions) are converted from global (extern) to local (static)?

Maybe. The linker *does* have less work to do when lots of functions are static -- the symbol tables the linker builds will be smaller, and the lookup in them will be faster.

This is unlikely to be measurable in practice -- you'll probably have to have tens of thousands of symbols, and you'll have to convert 90% of them to `static` before you can actually observe the speedup.

> Should I expect similar results if the objects have been created using a 'Release' compilation instead of 'Debug' compilation?

Possibly. In `C++`, with optimization on, a lot of functions may get inlined. This in turn leaves less work to do for the linker.

> Does the linkage specifier (extern/static) have any effect in the size of
> the object files?

UNIX systems traditionally include local symbols in the `.o` for debugging, and thus `extern` vs. `static` will have no effect.

But you can use `strip` to remove unnecessary (for further linking) symbols, and then the `.o` with `static` functions will have smaller symbol table.